# Lightgallery: Fit Image to Browser Window

Tags: javascript, css, image, plugins, lightgallery

I use the Lightgallery Plugin for my image gallery. It works perfectly but there is something which is not perfect. I want to fit the images into the browser window.

It works when the resolution of the image is higher than the resolution of the browser window. But when it is smaller it doesn´t fit.

Here is the plugin:
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

Does anybody have an idea or script to solve the problem?

Thanks, 
Jannis

Answer (score 1):

seems like a bit old, but if anyone is looking for this, you can try:

```
img.lg-object.lg-image {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps as it did for me:

```
img.lg-object.lg-image {
    height: inherit !important;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me in Lightgallery v1.2.6:

```
.lg-outer .lg-img-wrap {
    max-width:100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```